# What is an ES Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and the likewise inspired [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

If a number conforms to a certain rule, I call it an ES Number™. Otherwise, I call it an OS Number™ Use the following examples to find the rule:

[image: ES Numbers™ and OS Numbers™]

Here is a CSV:

```
ES Numbers™,OS Numbers™
4,5
96,48
343,434
2048,1024
15679,14679
86420,97531
1234567,6543210
543543543,210210210
3597175319,1354279860
8406268402,9068731254
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each number can be tested for whether it is an ES Number™ or an OS Number™ on its own. In particular, a number's relationship to other numbers in the sequence is irrelevant.

These are not the only examples of ES or OS Numbers™, more can be found.

**EDIT: SORRY TO EVERYONE WHO ATTEMPTED THIS PUZZLE**

I made a mistake in my ES Numbers™ list. 24 is actually an OS Number™. In order to make something similar to the original, I have included 96 which is an ES Number™. Unfortunately this makes the puzzle less cruel. ;)

Once again, sorry for the time you may or may not have wasted. I double-checked the puzzle and still didn't pick up the mistake. Now it is solvable in the intended way. (I've triple checked that)

Comment: E and O most likely stand for even and odd

Comment: There is an issue in your numbers, the last ES number in the table is `8406269402`, but in the CSV it's `8406268402`.

Comment: Does E'S stand for anything

Comment: @ev3commander: Veryl likely, but that's for us to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ES Number™ is a number that:

> Uses an even number of segments when shown in a seven-segment display.

ES and OS stand for

> Even-segmented and odd-segmented

Comment: @boboquack there are three 2s, so the count is odd (ones and zeros are out because 1^2=1 and 10^2=100). If this isn't correct, I think we need more examples.

Comment: It is correct, but that wasn't my reasoning. See whether you can find a simpler way to express it and I may accept your answer. Problem is, Rubio posted an answer that says the same thing so I can't accept your answer. There is a simpler way...

Comment: @boboquack I looked at Rubio's answer and saw that my earlier rule failed for 1234567. This one shouldn't...

Comment: Correct - I've added a bit more info in an edit.

Comment: That'll teach me to step away for a few hours. :)  Congrats ffao for figuring out what the pattern means!

Answer (score 4):

I wonder whether ES numbers are simply those

> whose digits have an *even sum* (hence ES).

There is a single obstacle to this, which is that

> the digits of 48 add up to 12, which is even.

Is it possible that that one is a mistake?

> Perhaps it was intended to be 12 (half the number in the ES column) rather than 48 (twice the number in the ES column).

Comment: No, that 48 was intentional. It was purposely there to stop such a solution. (It was probably a bit cruel of me to create the numbers like that). +1 anyway for spotting the problem.

Comment: Well, this is why I didn't post an answer. I discovered it when checking all the sums to test that, but... yeah. Very mean, @boboquack! (No, kidding, nicely done.)

Comment: @Alenanno I think digital sums are too easy for the types of puzzlers that populate this website.

Comment: Me too, which is why I was a little surprised to find things looking so much as if they were the answer :-).

Comment: See my edit: it doesn't change the 48 but does change the 24.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution, though if it's the intended one I'll be surprised.
Nevertheless, since it works to distinguish between the given ES and OS lists, I'll post it.

First let's assign ...

> a PSEValue of 0 to the digits 1,4,6,9,0.
>  a PSEValue of 1 to the digits 2,3,5,7,8.
>
>  I don't have a particular justification for these PSEValues, other than the fact that these choices happen to make the pattern work, which is why I assume this isn't the actual solution.

Then we use that to find, for each number in the lists,

> a sum of the PSEValues assigned to each digit in the number.

This gives us:

> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Bbb{ES\ Numbers}^\text{TM}&\Bbb{OS\ Numbers}^\text{TM}\\\hline^{4: 0 → 0}&^{5: 1 → 1}\\^{96: 0+0 → 0}&^{48: 0+1 → 1}\\^{343: 1+0+1 → 2}&^{434: 0+1+0 → 1}\\^{2048: 1+0+0+1 → 2}&^{1024: 0+0+1+0 → 1}\\^{15679: 0+1+0+1+0 → 2}&^{14679: 0+0+0+1+0 → 1}\\^{86420: 1+0+0+1+0 → 2}&^{97531: 0+1+1+1+0 → 3}\\^{1234567: 0+1+1+0+1+0+1 → 4}&^{6543210: 0+1+0+1+1+0+0 → 3}\\^{543543543: 1+0+1+1+0+1+1+0+1 → 6}&^{210210210: 1+0+0+1+0+0+1+0+0 → 3}\\^{3597175319: 1+1+0+1+0+1+1+1+0+0 → 6}\ &^{1354279860: 0+1+1+0+1+1+0+1+0+0 → 5}\ \\^{8406268402: 1+0+0+0+1+0+1+0+0+1 → 4}\ &^{9068731254: 0+0+0+1+1+1+0+1+1+0 → 5}\ \\\hline\end{array}$$

So the numbers are called ES Numbers™ or OS Numbers™ depending on

> whether the sum of the PSEValues for their digits is an Even Sum or an Odd Sum.

<sub>*upgraded MagicValues to PSEValues, to fit the revised puzzle.*</sub>

Comment: It's magic... not quite. There is a more logical solution. Anyway, nice TEX table. If it was about magic values the problem would be EMVS and OMVS numbers ;)

Comment: I had to try.  And, well, it *does* fit .... ;)   (And, incidentally, is the only set of MagicValues for the digits that makes the ES/OS lists work. Fun!)

Comment: Did you check with a computer program?

Comment: Yes I did indeed.

Comment: See my edit. Sorry for making you go to the trouble of writing a computer program for nothing.

Comment: Oh, dear. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Your PSEValues are correct, but why? ffao has posted a reason but it's not correct. Whoever finds a simple reason first will be accepted.